# Run QTabWidget made with designer in code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I created the GUI with tabs for different views per tab (like Chrome) that I need for my application with designer. Now I have issues running it with my Python code. Before I worked with MainWindow and that works fine, but after using the new .ui data it doesnt work anymore.

I tried the same method as with MainWindow, but there seems to be no Ui_tabWidget. I am probably mistaken how the setup of the ui works so I tried  something that worked with MainWindow.

for MainWindow:

```
class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For TabWidget:

```
class MyForm(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() #or Ui_TabWidget which doesnt exist
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the design based on a QTabWidget for it when you use Qt Designer you must select it in the *Widgets* section:

[image]

The generated .ui is the following:

**tabwidget.ui**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>TabWidget</class>
 <widget class="QTabWidget" name="TabWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>TabWidget</string>
  </property>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Then you must convert the .ui to .py:

```sh
pyuic5 tabwidget.ui -o tabwidget_ui.py -x
```

Generating the following tabwidget_ui.py:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'tabwidget.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_TabWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, TabWidget):
        TabWidget.setObjectName("TabWidget")
        TabWidget.resize(400, 300)

        self.retranslateUi(TabWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(TabWidget)

    def retranslateUi(self, TabWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        TabWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("TabWidget", "TabWidget"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    TabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
    ui = Ui_TabWidget()
    ui.setupUi(TabWidget)
    TabWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then you import it into the main.py:

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from tabwidget_ui import Ui_TabWidget


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_TabWidget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At the end the folder will have the following files:

```sh
├── main.py
├── tabwidget.ui
└── tabwidget_ui.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer, you rock!